# Error: Cannot find module 'grpc_node.node'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Hosting and Cloud Functions. When I execute `firebase serve --only functions` I got this error :

> Cannot start emulator. Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v57-darwin-x64-unknown/grpc_node.node'

I installed all dependencies required like firebase-tools.
I used [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `npm install -g firebase-tools` completed successfully?

Comment: Yes i did it many times

Comment: It didn't work in local but when I deploy it, it works. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The same issue with me.

You need to change your Node to **v6.14.0**. This is the version that will be running your code in Cloud Functions environment, please check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

When you change it, delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`.

Comment: maybe this will help someone who is facing this issues. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: delete ```node_modules``` folder and run ```npm install ``` works for me :)